# Nodelist or Html collection not iterating

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I'm trying to iterate over some elements and I'm not getting anything back.  I've tried :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")
```

and

```
document.querySelectorAll("myClass")
```

in which case I get an empty NodeList, or an HTML collection.  Either way, I am unable to iterate through either of them.  I've tried forEach, forOf, and the standard for loop.  I've also read through several posts about how to fix this (Array.from and so on) and nothing seems to work.

````
const counters = document.querySelectorAll("percentage-count");
const speed = 200;

counters.forEach((counter) => {
    console.log(counter);
});

for (let i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
    console.log(counters[i]);
};
```

Am I missing something really obvious here?  I can't seem to figure this out!!!
````

Comment: Sounds like the elements don't exist at the time you run the loop. Either because your code is in head before the elements with no load event listener or the elements get inserted with javascript after your code runs. Not enough known here without a [mcve]

Comment: What does `console.log(counters.length)` show you?

Comment: console.log(counters.length) is 0.  This is a WP site so I am enqueueing the script via functions.php

Comment: Try wrapping in `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {/* your code*/})` and see what that does. If counters length is still zero then there is probably some ajax loading content after dom loads and you would need to use MutationObserver

Comment: Yes, it is still at 0.

Comment: Assuming selector is correct they are being added to dom after your code runs

Comment: Hmm.  Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: Research how `MutationObserver ` APi works, or use a setInterval to keep checking for the elements and clear that interval when they are discovered